# "aws is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" is occured when I using package.json scripts

Tags: reactjs, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is part of my `package.json` scripts.

```json
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "aws s3 sync ./out s3://[my bucket name] --acl public-read --delete"
}
```

And I set `alias` using `.bashrc` like below

```
alias aws="winpty C:/Program\ Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/aws.exe"
```

`aws --version` works

```bash
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.8.2 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

And `s3 sync` command also works (Ignore permission issues. I will fix later).

```bash
$ aws s3 sync ./out s3://[my bucket name] --acl public-read --delete
fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

But when I try to use scripts... **Boom! Error Occurred!**

```bash
$ npm run deploy

> myProject@0.1.0 deploy
> aws s3 sync ./out s3://[my bucket name] --acl public-read --delete

'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I clear this hurdle?

Comment: You're on Windows? Using e.g. git bash? By default NPM uses cmd.exe: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell

Comment: Jon is right. You probably need something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/144348) to run that `alias` command every time `cmd.exe` is started.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, that is, I set the alias using bashrc, but if I use npm, it is useless because it uses cmd instead of git bash?

Comment: @acdcjunior Okay, now I know what the problem is, I'll reserch about this. thank you.

Comment: FWIW I think your `package.json` is good as it is. This is more a problem in the current machine than in the script itself.

Comment: @acdcjunior yeah, The information you recommended was very helpful.([this](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-quivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux/144348#144348))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have...

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "aws some-params"
}
```

...and you do...

```
npm run deploy
```

...[how NPM will run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#description) that script (namely, `aws some-params`) is platform dependent. From [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#description):

> By default, on Unix-like systems it is the `/bin/sh` command, on Windows it is `cmd.exe`. The actual shell referred to by `/bin/sh` also depends on the system. You can customize the shell with the `script-shell` configuration.

So when you get the error:

> `'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

If you google it you'll notice it is exactly in the format of errors thrown by `cmd.exe`.

Now, you say you use `.bashrc` to define `aws` as an `alias`. It is good, but that will only work when your shell is **git bash**, that is, `cmd.exe` will have no knowledge of that `alias` and thus will throw an error -- as it does.

### The fix

Now, you have some possibilities:

You can edit the windows registry to add something similar to a `.bashrc` to `cmd.exe` (see how to accomplish that [here](https://superuser.com/a/144348)).

Alternatively, you can set the `script-shell` for your NPM. Either you can [set it in your `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell), e.g.,

```
"script-shell": "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe",
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "aws some-params"
}
```

Or you can set it globally:

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Of course, all of this assuming your *git bash* is at `C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe`.